# Refactor Serverfault FAQ

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

When I go to [ServerFault.com/Unanswered](https://serverfault.com/unanswered) I always see the **How Does ServerFault Work? (The Community FAQ)**.  Can we refactor this so that it has an answer (which then can be upvoted) and thereby get this of the top of the unanswered page?